# Trying to display the data in my SharePoint Online Custom List by using Web Part Page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, sharepoint

```
<script>
    //AngularJS Code goes here
    var appVar = angular.module('listApp', ['ngRoute']);
    appVar.controller("controller1", function($scope){});
    function GetListItems($scope, EmployeeList){    
        var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/sites/angularjsexercise/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeList')/items?$select=Firstname,Middlename,Lastname"; 
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: {"Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose"},
            success: function(data)
            {
                $scope.items = data.d.results;
            },
                error: function(sender, args)
            {
                console.log(args.get_message());
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

here's the code, and I think the url is the reason why the data can't be fetch but I tried so many ways to properly link it but none works

Comment: Do you see any results/data if you manually navigate to `{your site url}/_api/sites/angularjsexercise/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeList')/items?$select=Firstname,Middlename,Lastname` in your web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Missing '/' before _api, sample test script in my online environment.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spApp = angular.module('listApp', []);
        spApp.controller('controller1', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            }).success(function (data) {
                var dataResults = data.d.results;
                $scope.listitems = dataResults;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("error");
                });
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="listApp">
        <div ng-controller="controller1">
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                <li ng-repeat="item in listitems">
                    {{item.Title}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```